# Ginn and Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: multi-touch

I am trying to use Ginn on Ubuntu 14.04.  I have already installed it via the command line but don't know how to actually use it with my touch screen (lenovo x220 tablet).

This [link](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Multitouch/Ginn) states that "you can use Ginn to assign gestures in the global section to Compiz Shortcuts" before listing some code to paste.  But where exactly is the "global section to Compiz Shortcuts"?

Answer (score 1):

Ginn keeps settings in `/etc/ginn/wishes.xml`

Default configuration already includes shortcuts mentioned in wiki